# Install python packages via npm

Tags: python, npm, dependencies, pip

I am interested in dependency resolution out of curiosity.

How can I install **python** packages on a linux server via npm?

Maybe I am too old, but I personally think it is childish that every programming language community does re-invent the dependency resolution stuff on his own. Why not use npm for other languages?

**Update**

I ask out of curiosity, and to learn new stuff. I don't want to blame pip. But I was asked to provide details. Here you see [pip needs a dependency resolver](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988)

Comment: How does `pip` not resolve dependencies? Could you give a detailed explanation or an example?

Comment: Agree. An example package would help. It resolved dependencies for all packages I have installed. Maybe the package doesn't list something as a dependency?